# Set corner radius on view after view loads

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view coming from a class and I want to set the corner radius equal to half it's width.

The width is a computed property made using autolayout. So normally I'd set the corner radius property in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` like so

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    c.largeProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = c.largeProfileImage.frame.width / 2
}
```

But the largeProfileImage isn't an initial view it gets called after viewdidLoad and I animate it on a tap gesture. Below is where the view is animated onto screen. It is created in this same function.

```
     //I tried setting the cornerRadius here as well but it isn't setting.

    //c.largeProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = c.largeProfileImage.frame.width / 2


    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        self.profileImageContainerCenterY?.constant = -(c.profileImageContainer.frame.height) * 2
        self.profileSettingsContainerCenterY?.constant = 0

        c.profileSettingsContainer.alpha = 1
        c.largeProfileImage.alpha = 1

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { (completed) in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the profileImage

```
let largeProfileImage: UIImageView = {
    let pv = UIImageView()
    pv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    pv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    pv.clipsToBounds = true
    pv.image = UIImage(named: "user")

    pv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return pv
}()
```

Comment: adding views from Class views is on same controller where class is declared ? or adding class in Controller A and views of Class from Controller A to Controller B?

Comment: Have you tried adding the cornerRadius inside viewDidLayoutSubviews method?please try in this mehod , may be it will help to set the cornerRadius after all the views are laid out

Comment: you need to add `largeProfileImage.layer.masksToBounds = false` and `largeProfileImage.clipsToBounds = true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able successfully to debug the issue.

Since the width was a computed property it was 0 before the layout was laid out meaning

```
c.largeProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = c.largeProfileImage.frame.width / 2

self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

resulted in a corner radius of zero.

So the solution...

was to call it afterwards the width was to set the corner radius after the width was computed.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

c.largeProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = c.largeProfileImage.frame.width / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For proper animation change the sequence like this.

```
    self.profileImageContainerCenterY?.constant = -(c.profileImageContainer.frame.height) * 2
    self.profileSettingsContainerCenterY?.constant = 0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    c.profileSettingsContainer.alpha = 1
    c.largeProfileImage.alpha = 1
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The animation is fine it gets animate in. The issue is the corner radius isn't getting set

Comment: add c.largeProfileImage.clipsToBounds = true after you set the corner radius.

Comment: also why are you calling layoutIf needed in completion handler. It is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The three lines below is necessary to get a round image-

```
image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.width / 2
image.layer.masksToBounds = false
image.clipsToBounds = true
```

You might see a rounded `UIImage` but you may also notice the image squared inside of the circle and to solve that you may have play around with the `contentMode`. Most of the time `.scaleAspectFill` does the job.

Comment: can't access self when creating the view... Will include the view in an edit.

Comment: in your update  it should be `masksToBounds = false`

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the fact that I'm getting the view from a class and I'm not referencing the view correctly. Or the fact that the width is a computed property and the corner radius is being set when the width is equal to 0. I can't call viewWillLayoutSubviews in the function though.

Comment: can you comment the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and test?

Comment: Problem still persists.

Comment: Can you just initialize a variable in your `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and in the variable declaration use a `didSet` to set the imageView's properties? The variable can just be a simple `Bool` so `var simpleBool: Bool = false{ didSet { //set the UIImageView here if simpleBool is true}}` and set `simpleBool = true` inside `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. So every time `simpleBool` is set to `true` the code inside `didSet` would fire and set your `imageView` to circle.